# How can I connect to my GitLab omnibus LDAP server to running in a container?

Tags: gitlab, ldap, gitlab-omnibus

I have been trying to work on this for weeks.

root@git:/# gitLab-rake gitlab:ldap:check

```
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
Deprecation warning: Net::LDAP::ConnectionRefused will be deprecated. Use Errno::ECONNREFUSED instead.
Deprecation warning: Net::LDAP::ConnectionRefused will be deprecated. Use Errno::ECONNREFUSED instead.
Could not connect to the LDAP server: Connection refused - connect(2) for 172.17.0.2:389

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

These are the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb files:

```rb
 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false


###! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'GitLab LDAP'
     host: 'git.example.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     bind_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
     password: 'example'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: false
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: true
     lowercase_usernames: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'OU=users,dc=example,dc=com'
     user_filter: ''
#     ## EE only
     group_base: 'cn=my_group,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'
     admin_group: 'my_admin_group'

 EOS
```

Is there any work around this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think GitLab Omnibus bundles an LDAP server. Maybe that's the source of your confusion here? The configuration is meant for you to point to an existing LDAP server that _you_ created somewhere else. GitLab must be able to communicate with your external LDAP server.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm new to this Self-managed GitLab server. Thank you for pointing this out.